# Inner join in excel

Tags: excel

Currently I am trying to create inner join in excel (It is my homework). The excel should work like this:
I paste item codes and prices from one supplier (col. A and B), then I paste the item codes and prices from other supplier (col. D and E). The output from this template should be item code and difference between those two prices (col G and H).

***For example image:***

[image]

I have tried to crawl through many forums. I have found examples of inner joins with vlookup, but no example in which there would be calculated the difference between the prices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VLOOKUP()` formula to achieve your goal.

```
=VLOOKUP(G1,$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(G1,$D$1:$E$5,2)
```

[image]

Comment: you are missing a `FALSE` in your second `VLOOKUP`